# How does scaffolding functionality works in some of the Node Packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

For some Node packages, (Eg - `create-react-app`) when we run `npx create-react-app app-name` or `npm create-react-app app-name` (if we have npm installed globally) in cli, then the command line automatically creates a physical folder with basic files to run a React app. What technology, or modules does Node packages as such use to allow this kind of scaffolding of project?

I saw that there is something called [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) which helps users to do such thing, or a module called `fs` which I am assuming could be used to help to generate the scaffolding. Does `create-react-app` or any other Node Packages that does scaffolding uses similar technology?

Comment: There are an unlimited number of ways scaffolding could be generated. "fs" is the file system module--it's likely anything that creates files uses it in one form or another. It's open-source--you can find out how CRA or any other open source project does it.

Comment: Creating react application for building own application has so many node package modules. For example when you see packages installed in package.json, you can see many modules' names are placed in the JSON file.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for your comments! I guess I would have to look into the public repository on GitHub to exactly figure out how such packages generate its scaffolding.

Comment: @jacobkim Thank you! I'll definitely look into the node_modules installed in such Node Package repository :)